# How to Rails rake multiple commands with one environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there a way to do multiple Rails 3 rake commands on one line, requiring the environment to be initiated only once?

I know this is possible:

```
rake db:rollback db:migrate
```

But if options are passed,

```
rake db:migrate VERSION=0 db:migrate
```

the second 'db:migrate' won't run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that is possible.

The quickest solution I can think of is:

```
RAILS_ENV=test rake db:migrate VERSION=0 && rake db:migrate
```

The reason why I believe this is not possible is because `VERSION` is simply a constant, not an attribute that is passed as a `db:migrate` option. For example, all of these commands work:

`rake db:migrate VERSION=0`

`rake VERSION=0 db:migrate`

`VERSION=0 rake db:migrate`

And since you can't rewrite the constant in the same action again, you basically call `db:migrate VERSION=0` twice.

Comment: That would initialize the environment twice, which I don't want to do. In rake db:rollback db:migrate--it works great. Only initializes once for both commands.

Comment: I updated my answer, still no solution for this, but at least an explanation why I believe this isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try [Zeus](https://github.com/burke/zeus)?

It preloads environments for rails, rake, test environments, etc.